# React : Access data in .json file to check if it matches with an input

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm doing a dashboard about covid. I want to use a json file but the way data is encapsulated causes me an issue.
[image]

As you can see, the "real" name of the country is written inside the "location" field  inside the "airport" name. Is there a way I can sort of bypass the "airport" name to access "location" field ? (Maybe like going through all of the "airport" names and search for location inside of them or looking for "location" field directly). Then I will be able to check if the country written in the input matches with one country inside the json file.
There are only these 2 layers ("airport" name & what's inside) in the json file.

About my code, I'm usig react. For now I just fecth the url of the json file to get it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone faces the same issue as me, this helped me find what to do :

1. Object.keys(data)
   Creates an array consisting of all the keys present in the object
2. Object.values(data)
   Creates an array consisting of all the values present in the object
3. Object.entries(data)
   Creates an array consisting of both the keys and values present in the object

In my case, to get location I do this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.values(data).length; i++) {
            if (this.state.country === Object.values(data)[i].location) {
                this.setState({
                    post: Object.values(data)[i]
                })
            }
        }
```